# What is the shorthand in d3 for the identity function ("function(d) { return d; }")?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Looking through the d3 docs, I see this code (the identity function) repeated everywhere:

```
function(d) { return d; }
```

Is there a built-in way in d3 to do this? I know I could create my own no-op identity function and use it everywhere, but it seems like d3 should provide this.

Comment: The [Functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) library has a method called "K" that, given a value, returns a function that returns that value.  That library is written as an exercise in providing a functional programming platform, however, so it's kind-of odd.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I'd prefer to stick to something that's provided by d3, if possible.

Comment: D3 doesn't provide this.

Comment: Also, [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org) provides `_.identity`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used to see Mike do .data(Object) which seems to work

http://tributary.io/inlet/5842519

but I'm not sure why I don't see it around anymore

```
var svg = d3.select("svg")

var data = [[10,20],[30,40]];
svg.selectAll("g")
.data(data)
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate(" + [i * 100, 0] + ")"})
.selectAll("circle")
//.data(function(d) { console.log(d); return d })
.data(Object)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr({
  cx: function(d,i) { return 100 + i * 40 },
  cy: 100,
  r: function(d,i) { return d }
})
```

Comment: One limitation that I've found of the above is that while `Object(3)` acts in most cases like `3`, it doesn't pass the `===` test.

Comment: "`Object`"? Not very clear meaning in my opinion. Then I prefer `function(d) { return d; }` because it's obvious what happens.

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering why there wasn't a `d3.identity` function as part of the library, and couldn't find a reason not to have one.

From a performance point of view, defining an identity function gives better performance than reusing the `Object` constructor. It makes little difference if you reuse the same identity function across different types. Some [performance tests are here](http://jsperf.com/identity-function-reuse).

So in my case I abuse D3 and added the function myself:

```
d3.identity = function(d) { return d; }
```

If you're using [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) then you can also use the [_.identity](http://underscorejs.org/#identity) function.

Regarding using the `Object` constructor, my *assumption* is that this creates a new, unnecessary object each time it's called which wastes memory and CPU time, both for creation and garbage collection. This may be optimised away for immutable types such as numbers in some runtimes.

**EDIT** Phrogz has a [brief article](http://phrogz.net/fewer-lambdas-in-d3-js) showing some useful shorthand for reducing the number of lambdas when working with D3, that includes an identity function.

Comment: Frustratingly, d3 even defines several identity functions in its [internal implementation](https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js) but only exposes identity$5, identity$6, and identity$8 (as geoIdentity, scaleIdentity, and zoomIdentity respectively). Unfortunately only identity, identity$1, identity$3, identity$4, and identity$7 are the desired implementation.